# Qt error trying to install quiteinsane gimp plugin

Tags: application-development, compiling, qt, gimp

I am trying to install the quiteinsane gimp plugin on Ubuntu 16.04.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/quiteinsane/

I am getting this error:

```
checking for Qt... configure: error: Qt (>= Qt 2.2.2) (headers and libraries) not found. Please check your installation!
```

After searching the web, I have done

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5-*    
sudo apt-get install libqt4-*    
sudo apt-get install libqt3-*
```

I still keep getting this error.

I have even installed Qt5 in my home directory, following the instructions on the web on how to do it,

https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu

but I don't know how to make the installer recognize that. Someone had suggested adding the include and lib paths of the install in the configure line, but that did not work either. This was the configure command I used then:

```
./configure --enable-mt --with-qt-includes=/home/skumar/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/include --with-qt-libraries=/home/skumar/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib
```

Thanks for any help.

Kumar